# GMail API Node.js quickstart - ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: gmail-api

I am trying the [GMail API Node.js quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs) on Windows 10.

I do get the expected

[image: Authorisation Message].

However when I visit the url I get

[image: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED]

> for http://localhost/?code=4/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.radonly

I get this error after going through `'This app isn't verified'/'Advanced > Go to {Project Name} (unsafe)'.` message.

No Proxy active and also tried with AntiVirus disabled.

Any ideas what the problem could be?
Thanks.

Comment: There should be a link towards the bottom of the popup where you can use the app anyway while you are testing it  I have a video that shows you how. [Google hasn’t verified this app, what now? How to fix It!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6935WKdaH6E)

Comment: Yes, I did click 'Continue' at 'Google hasn't verified this app. The ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED occurs after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are having is that you are runing a `Authorization credentials for a desktop application.`  Google made a change recently which deprecated the [oob redirect](https://developers.googleblog.com/2022/02/making-oauth-flows-safer.html#dates-oob).  This means that now you need to use localhost or 127.0.0.1 as a redirect endpoint for installed applications.

Resulting them in returning the authorization code back to the browser showing site can not be reached because your not running a web app you are running an installed application.

If you check the url the authorization code you are looking for to add to your code can be found there.  just take that code and submit it where it  asks for it.

```
Enter the code from that page here:
```

There is currently no other option and no way to fix this unless you want to start up a web server in node. basicly its working as intended and Google is in the process of updating all the Javascript samples to reflect that.

Comment: Thank you so much @DalmTo, I was able to extract the auth code from the url as you suggested!

Comment: I am in contact with Google oauth team trying to find a way to be more clear as to how things work.  IMO Javascript sample should not be a desktop app sample it should be a web application sample.   It would be easer for developers like yourself to understand.